# Make a selected word bold in the text of a HTML-styled JtextPane?

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtextpane, bold

How can I get the selected word in the text from a `JTextPane` and then apply the Bold property for the selected-text by using the `Ctrl+B` Short Cut.

String are given to the `JTextpane` from the xml files. String are get from the tag elements and set to the `JTextpane`:

```
String selectedText = ta_textpane.getSelectedText();
int getselectedtextstart = ta_textpane.getSelectionStart();
int getselectedtextend = ta_textpane.getSelectionEnd();

String textbef = text.substring(0, getselectedtextstart);
String textaft = text.substring(getselectedtextend, text.length());
String textinbet = "<b>" + text.substring(getselectedtextstart,getselectedtextend) + "</b>";

String settoxmlfiletag = textbef + textinbet + textaft
```

After concat the `bold(<b>)`, write the  bolded string to the xml tag. i have a Problem in getting the last index position and first index position because i use the `tamil` language in the `JTextPane`

Bold is applied but cannot be applied in the correct position.

Comment: `JTextPane` isn't really meant for displaying html, instead you should be using a `JEditorPane` or setting the style for the `StyledDocument`

Comment: Some tags(<>) are cannot be shown by JEditorpane,so only i will use the JTextPane.

Comment: please tell the suggestion for me to get the extact bold for the selected values

Comment: Maybe you should explain exactly what it is you are trying to do?  Do you want the text to be **bold** in the editor or simple insert `<b>...</b>` around the text in the editor

Comment: My problem is insert the bold property for the selectText from the Jtextpane..  Bold is Applied to other nearest word also...

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I don't know why you need to use `getSelectionStart` and `getSelectionEnd` when you already have the selected text...

Comment: how to apply the Bold property to the Selectedtext?

Comment: `textinbet = "<b>" + selectedText + "</b>"`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution is to use the `insertHTML()` method from `HTMLEditorKit`:

```
public class Bold extends JTextPane {       

    public Bold(){
        super();

        setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
        setText("<html><h1>Example</h1><p>Just a test</p></html>");
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_B, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK), "bold");
        getActionMap().put("bold", new AbstractAction(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTextPane bold = (JTextPane) e.getSource();
                int start = bold.getSelectionStart();
                int end = bold.getSelectionEnd();
                String txt = bold.getSelectedText();
                if(end != start)
                    try {
                        bold.getDocument().remove(start, end-start);
                        HTMLEditorKit htmlkit = (HTMLEditorKit) bold.getEditorKit();
                        htmlkit.insertHTML((HTMLDocument) bold.getDocument(), start, "<b>"+txt+"</b>", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.B);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setContentPane(new Bold());
            f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480));
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true); 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not good if you select a text fragment with different attributes. E.g. there are 2 words and one of them is underlined. You select them both and try to make it bold. You approach removes existing attributes

Answer (score 2):

When your text is selected, just call `HTMLEditorKit.BoldAction.actionPerformed`.

`InsertHTML` is also a good solution, but the parameters can be problematic in some circumstances.