# How to set next text to be bold Action listener[java]

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I was trying to create a bold function for a text editor but i do not know how to set the next text you type to bold formatting.(I just want to be clear that this is not about setting selected text to bold, instead setting text you type in the future to bold) I was trying

```
JEditorPane feild2 = new JEditorPane("text/html","");
JButton Button=new JButton("B");
Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg4) {
    int e=0;
    if(arg4.getSource()==Button&&e==0){
        feild2.setText(feild2.getText()+ "<b>");
        e=1;
    }
    else if(arg4.getSource()==Button&&e==1){
        feild2.setText(feild2.getText()+ "</b>");
        e=0;
    }
}

});
```

but that was not working. Any Suggestions?

Comment: How do you think this can work? It just bolds out text at the moment button is pressed. There is no code to listen for future text and make it bold as well.

Comment: I'd start with [How to use Editor Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) and [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html), then you could have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241960/make-a-selected-word-bold-in-the-text-of-a-html-styled-jtextpane) and [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SimpleAttributeBoldItalic.htm) and [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/EditorbasedonJTextPane.htm)

Comment: Remember, `setText` says, "throw away the previous text content and apply this new text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the default Action provided by the `StyledEditorKit`:

```
JButton button = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction() );
```

If you click the button with selected text then the text will be made bold.

If you click the button when no text is selected, the text inserted at the caret will be bold.